# D3.js Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm pretty new to d3.js and to web too. I wanted to ue a csv file to plot a line graph but I got some errors I can't really fix:

[image]

Here is the code:

```css
body,html{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.95em;
 text-align: center;
}
#chart{
 background-color: #F5F2EB;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.bar{
 fill: purple;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.bar-label{
 fill: black;
 text-anchor: middle;
 font-size: 18px;
}
.axis path,
.axis line{
 fill: none;
 stroke: #000;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.gridline path,
.gridline line{
 fill: none;
 stroke: #ccc;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Learning D3</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Place all DOM elements here -->
<script>

var data= [
 d3.csv("refugee_data.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    /*year: new Date(+d.Year, 0, 1), // convert "Year" column to Date
    make: d.Make,
    model: d.Model,
    length: +d.Length // convert "Length" column to number*/
  date: d.Year + "/" +d.Month,
  origin: d.Origin,
  asylum: d.Asylum,
  value: +d.Value
  };
}, function(error, rows) {
  console.log(rows);
})
];

var w = 800;
var h = 450;
var margin = {
 top: 58,
 bottom: 100,
 left: 80,
 right: 40
};
var width = w - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("id", "chart")
   .attr("width", w)
   .attr("height", h);
var dateParser = d3.time.format("%Y/%B").parse;
var x = d3.time.scale()
   .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){
   var date = dateParser(d.date);
   return date;
  }))
  .range([0,width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
   return d.value;
  })])
  .range([height,0]);

function plot(params){
  //enter()
  this.selectAll(".point")
    .data(params.data)
    .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .classed("point", true)
     .attr("r", 2);
  //Update
  this.selectAll(".point")
  .attr("cx", function(d){
   var date = dateParser(d.date);
   return x(date);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d){
   return y(d.value);
  })

  //Exit()
  this.selectAll(".point")
  .data(params.data)
  .exit()
  .remove();
}
plot.call(chart, {
 data: data
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this ist my a part of my csv, pretty basic so I don't get why it does not work.

Asylum,Origin,Year,Month,Value

Germany,Afghanistan,2014,January,981
Germany,Afghanistan,2014,February,781
Germany,Afghanistan,2014,March,675
Germany,Afghanistan,2014,April,673
Germany,Afghanistan,2014,May,523
Germany,Afghanistan,2014,June,621
Germany,Afghanistan,2014,July,752
Germany,Afghanistan,2014,August,743
Germany,Afghanistan,2014,September,922

I assume it is a really stupid mistake can you please help me out?

Comment: Are you debugging your code and know on which line you get the error?

Comment: the console say something in line 93 or 94

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is assuming that calling `d3.csv(...)` returns your CSV data.

`d3.csv` makes an AJAX call to load your data and then calls a callback function when that data has been loaded.  Your code continues running while the data loads in the background.  When you write `var data = [d3.csv(...)]`, `data` doesn't contain the data loaded from your CSV file, it contains only a d3 object, and you cannot plot that.

Instead, your call to `d3.csv` should look something like the following:

```
d3.csv("refugee_data.csv", function(d) {
  return {
        date: d.Year + "/" +d.Month,
        origin: d.Origin,
        asylum: d.Asylum,
        value: +d.Value
  };
}, function(error, rows) {
  console.log(rows);
  render(rows);
});
```

where `render` is a function that d3 will call to draw your graph when the data has finished loading.

I created a `render` function that contained the contents of your code from the line `var w = 800;` to the lines beginning `var y = ...`, followed by the contents of the `plot` function.  I also replaced `this.selectAll` with `svg.selectAll`, and remove the use of `plot.call`.  The `render` function I wrote ended up as follows:

```
function render(data) {
    var w = 800;
    var h = 450;
    var margin = {
        top: 58,
        bottom: 100,
        left: 80,
        right: 40
    };
    var width = w - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("id", "chart")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);
    var dateParser = d3.time.format("%Y/%B").parse;
    var x = d3.time.scale()
             .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){
                var date = dateParser(d.date);
                return date;
            }))
            .range([0,width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
                return d.value;
            })])
            .range([height,0]);   

        //enter()
        svg.selectAll(".point")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                    .append("circle")
                    .classed("point", true)
                    .attr("r", 2);
        //Update
        svg.selectAll(".point")
        .attr("cx", function(d){
            var date = dateParser(d.date);
            return x(date);
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d){
            return y(d.value);
        })

        //Exit()
        svg.selectAll(".point")
        .data(data)
        .exit()
        .remove();
}
```

After making these changes I was able to see your graph working.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Is there some  besides d3.keys to filter some entries of the csv? I want to filter the origin countries, like afghanistan an syria for interavtive purposes. In other terms I'd like to hover with the mous over the points to get the origin country. [This is the source](http://popstats.unhcr.org/en/asylum_seekers_monthly) to get an idea of the real data

Comment: @basedian: if you have a separate question, the thing to do is to ask a separate question. This is something I see that [you have now done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110708/d3-js-csv-filter-for-interactivity).