# D3.js - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: d3.js, svg, linechart

Taking a course in pluralsight and some of their materials are fairly outdated. Was wondering if anyone can help me understand what's going wrong with this error. Learning to put external data into d3. This is still running in version 3 of D3. I'm open to version 4 responses as well.

My CSV is set up like:

```
month,sales
20130101,38
20130201,35
20130301,41
20130401,55
20130501,58
20130601,66
20130701,74
20130801,78
20130901,38
20131001,30
20131101,26
20131201,29
```

I'm running my localhost so getting the data is fine, I can see it through console.log. I'm trying to portray a line chart with the data but I'm running into the error of getting the x and y coordinates.

```
var h = 100;
var w = 400;
var ds;

d3.csv("MonthlySales.csv", function(error, data) {

  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
  } else {
    console.log(data);
    ds = data;
  }
})

var lineFun = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) { return ((d.month - 20130001/ 3.25));})
      .y(function(d) { return h - d.sales;})
      .interpolate("linear")


var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr({ width: w, height: h});

var viz = svg.append("path")
              .attr({
                d: lineFun,
                "stroke": "purple",
                "stroke-width": 2,
                "fill": "none"
              });
```

How should I change my variable lineFun or my the d attribute of variable viz so I'm able to show the data?

Comment: `var viz = svg.append("path").datum(data).etc...`

Comment: In addition to what @GerardoFurtado mentioned, you need to understand that `d3.csv()` is an asynchronous call! Your `data` a.k.a. `ds` won't be available before the callback provided to that function is executed. You need to put the creation of the path, which depends on the data, **inside** that callback.

Comment: And in addition to the addition, pay attention to that object you're passing to `attr()`: that won't work in v4.x.

Comment: @altocumulus Thanks, I was able to make my D3 function work!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [D3.js Cannot read property 'length' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107705/d3-js-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined)