# Cannot Display Loaded Data Using d3.csv()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to read csv data using d3, and display each row as a paragraph.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type = 'text/javascript' src = 'd3.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type = 'text/javascript'>

        d3.csv('test.csv', function(data){  
                d3.select('body').selectAll('p').data(data).enter().append('p').text('new para');
            })

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The data is lines from a TV show, with columns for the speaker, season, episode, scene and dialog. When I view the Chrome console, this is what I see:

[Console View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBPWe.png)

Comment: can you reproduce the error in a snippet, that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34108214/4256677) may help